# Tomcat sample application doesn't start

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to run [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/) sample tomcat web application with **apache-tomcat-9.0.82** and java 8

I've moved the **sample.war** file to the recommended folder. Opened powershell with admin privileges:

```
PS C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\bin> .\startup.bat
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\webapps"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\webapps\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
```

a console page opens for half a second and then closes...

The **C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\logs** directory is empty

**EDIT**
I haven't touched any config file. There's no process running on port 8080

```
PS C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\bin> netstat -ano | findstr :8080
PS C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\bin>
```

Comment: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/installing-tomcat-9-on-windows/

Comment: _Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\webapps"_ I have a similar (version 9.0.36) Tomcat installation on my computer (Windows OS and JDK 8), but have a _Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-9.0.82\apache-tomcat-9.0.82"_ when I run the `startup.bat`. I don't know if that makes a difference. With a successful Tomcat startup the a console page should remain open and closes on shutdown. I am using Windows Command Prompt.

Comment: Try .\catalina.cmd run This will run the Tomcat in the current console and if any startup errors are encountered it should print on the console. Give it a try and check.